# Understanding nodes and how to append

Tags: javascript, html, json, object, nodes

I've been working on a project that some other developers had started and I'm trying to understand the code while also completing the project. Currently what I have is some json with links and a url text (pretty much a quick description), what I need to do is on a button click I want to display each of the links with their correct text and make it a clickable link. The way this needs to be done is using nodes which I'm not 100% knowledgeable on. If I need to explain this more please let me know also I have provided an example of what I'm currently working with. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JavaScript And JSON</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor='#CED3F3'>

    <button onclick="appendUrl()">Append</button><br>

<br><script id = "i">
    function category()
    //adding function with button click removes html page styling?
       {
        var category = {
                "content": [
                {
                "links": "basic information",
                "urlText": "Basis Information System",
                "urlDesc": "portal for technology development, people search, a keyword search ."
                },
                {
                "links": "http://site.com",
                "urlText": "Net",
                "urlDesc": "the entry page example"
                },
                {
                "links": "http://newsgroups.com",
                "urlText": "Newsgroups",
                "urlDesc": "information internal newsgroups, usage, tools, statistics, netiquette"
                },
                {
                "links": "http://site2.com",
                "urlText": "Another site",
                "urlDesc": "community for transfer of knowledge and technical information"
                },
                {
                "links": "http://news.com",
                "urlText": " some news",
                "urlDesc": "place with news"
                }
            ]
        }

</script>
<script>
    function appendUrl()
        {
        //there needs to be a loop here?
            var link = "needs to loop through links?"
            var node=document.createElement("LI");
            var nodeA=document.createElement("A");
            var textnode=document.createTextNode();
                node.appendChild(nodeA);
                nodeA.appendChild(textnode);
                nodeA.href=(link);
                nodeA.target="_blank";
                document.getElementById("i").appendChild(node);                     
        }   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you don't understand? That being said, a few comments about your current code: (1) function `category` does nothing, it should at least return your data; (2) on the other function, yes, you should be looping your data object; and (3), don't append html into a `<script>` element, append to a ul where list items are valid children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are going to need your category function to actually return the json data, otherwise it is of no use to anyone.

```
function category()
{
    var category = {
        "content": [
           ...
        ]
    }
    return category;
}
```

Then you can simply loop over the content array in the category object like this:

```
var content = category().content;
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var item = content[i];
    var link = item.links;
    var node=document.createElement("LI");
    var nodeA=document.createElement("A");
    var textnode=document.createTextNode(item.urlText);
    node.appendChild(nodeA);
    nodeA.appendChild(textnode);
    nodeA.href=(link);
    nodeA.target="_blank";
    document.getElementById("i").appendChild(node);  
}
```

However, if you're going to be creating list items in the markup, you are going to want to add them to a `ul` element, so you should have a `ul` somewhere in your markup like this:

```
<ul id="i"></ul>
```

And remove the `id="i"` from the script tag. You don't want to add the list items to the script.

Comment: ah this makes a lot more sense now, I will have to give this a try then for myself. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of stuff jquery makes very easy to accomplish - if you can use it in your project.

```
var ul = $("<ul></ul">);
for(var i in category.content){
  var li = $("<li></li>");
  var a = $("<a href='" + category.content[i].links + "'>" + category.content[i].urlText + "</a>");
  li.append(a);
  ul.append(li);
}
containerDiv.append(ul);
```

In your example you also make list items children of a script tag. Not sure what your goal was there but I would have a plain div.

If you *really* have to do it in plain javascript:

```
var containerDiv = document.getElementById("parent");
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
for(var i in category.content){
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = category.content[i].links;
  a.innerHTML = category.content[i].urlText;
  li.appendChild(a);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
containerDiv.appendChild(ul);
```

A fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kaYx8/)

Comment: I did consider using jQuery but I wanted to make sure I understood it at a more basic level first, this definitely helped a lot though thank you!